# Borrowed Canadian Money and paying back in US

Tags: canada, debt

My husband borrowed Canadian money from his relative to pay for his American education.  At the time the Canadian dollar was .50:1.  Now the exchange rate is 1:1 and we are paying back the debt in US dollars.  Does this mean that we owe twice as much?

Answer (score 11):

The all time low on the Canadian dollar was [61.79 US cents on Jan 21, 2002](http://www.cbc.ca/news/interactives/map-history-dollar/).

Yes, it will now cost you about US$1.01 to pay back a Canadian dollar, if when you borrowed you agreed to pay in their currency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So if his education was $300,000 USD should be pay back 447,000 to Canada?

Comment: @user9829: He should pay back in CAD what he borrowed in CAD. How much that is in USD is your problem, not the creditors'.

Comment: Yeah. He's _not_ paying back twice the debt, he's paying back the debt itself. The fact that the husband took on additional foreign exchange risk is _his_ problem, as MSalters points out, and one he could have mitigated.

Comment: Might help to view it from the relatively perspective. They gave you (made up numbers) $123,456 in CAD and are expecting to get back $123,456 in CAD plus possibly some interest depending on the terms. The relative would feel ripped off if you only tried to give him $75,500 in CAD.

Comment: @Kellenjb - aren't examples supposed to over-simplify? That's the oddest number to offer. How about every $1000 you got, cost your relative CAN$1618 to lend you. Now rates changed and It's US$1634 to pay it back.